# Unlock an Active Directory account via C#

Tags: c#, active-directory

I have a web/IIS server (Win2012R2) in which users authenticate against Active Directory (DC = Win2016). I cannot unlock an AD account via C# from this web server.  How can I do it?

Things I have tried or proven:

1. Creating a domain admin account and explicitly using those credentials when instantiating the `PrincipalContext`. Also logging into the domain controller with this admin account and unlocking the account successfully (manually).  Whether I pass in a `PrincipalContext` with hard-coded credentials or not, I can confirm that the credentials are valid in either case (ex. `ctx.ValidateCredentials("my_user", "my_pwd")`). I can confirm that my `UserPrincipal` is not null and that I am able to read the correct value of the user's locked status via `IsAccountLockedOut()`.
2. I can successfully unlock the account using PowerShell from the web server using any domain admin account.

Code:

```
string usr = HttpContext.Current.Session["CurrentUsername"].ToString();
PrincipalContext ctx = new PrincipalContext(ContextType.Domain);
UserPrincipal user = UserPrincipal.FindByIdentity(ctx, IdentityType.SamAccountName, usr);

if(user != null && user.IsAccountLockedOut()) {
    user.UnlockAccount();
}
```

Error:

> System.UnauthorizedAccessException: Access is denied.
>   at System.DirectoryServices.Interop.UnsafeNativeMethods.IAds.SetInfo()
>   at System.DirectoryServices.DirectoryEntry.CommitChanges()
>   at System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement.SDSUtils.WriteAttribute(String dePath, String attribute, Int32 value, NetCred credentials, AuthenticationTypes authTypes)
>   at System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement.ADStoreCtx.WriteAttribute(Principal p, String attribute, Int32 value)
>   at System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement.ADStoreCtx.UnlockAccount(AuthenticablePrincipal p)
>   at System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement.AccountInfo.UnlockAccount()
>   at ASP.en_us_forgot_aspx.btnPassword_OnClick(Object sender, EventArgs e)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue in my code was related to not defining the [PrincipalContext](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.directoryservices.accountmanagement.principalcontext?view=netframework-4.7.2) correctly.  Once I followed the documentation example precisely for [UserPrincipal Constructors](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.directoryservices.accountmanagement.userprincipal.-ctor?view=netframework-4.7.2), and discovered the OU path of the admin account I was using for the unlock, I solved the problem.

```
PrincipalContext ctx = new PrincipalContext(ContextType.Domain,
                                            "ad.domainname.com",
                                            "OU=SomeOU,DC=ad,DC=domainname,DC=com",
                                            "myadminuser",
                                            "MyPa$sW0rd");
```

Answer (score 0):

The context is not relevant here. The account running the web site process in IIS needs to have permission to do the unlock.

I have a site that does this, and I had to set the site in IIS to run using a special domain account created for that purpose that only has the exact specific permissions it needs. You don't need or want a full domain admin account exposed via a web site this way.