# Authentication user's WIndows Username and Password without triggering lockout in AD

Tags: c#, active-directory

I have an on-site (internal) application that uses Windows authentication.  On startup - the user is required to enter their AD username and password.  The application then validates this information using the UserPrincipal.ValidateCredentials() method.

**Desired Behavior**

The customer is asking the following:

- In case of invalid login attempts, do not increment the account lockout counter in AD
- Once login attempt threshold is exceeded, lock the web app, but do not lock the AD account.

**Besides this being a less-than ideal design, is this even possible?**

P.S. They swear they have other applications using AD credentials that do not lock out AD account if user enters wrong password.  I haven't gotten clear examples of that yet.

Comment: This would be a security risk as it would allow one to keep guessing passwords without consequence. The whole point of triggering a lockout is to prevent this.

Comment: Does the answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52632978/unlock-an-active-directory-account-via-c-sharp) solve the issue?

Comment: You may consider consulting with an attorney prior to proceeding.

Comment: [AuthenticablePrincipal.UnlockAccount Method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.directoryservices.accountmanagement.authenticableprincipal.unlockaccount?view=dotnet-plat-ext-7.0)

Comment: Yes exactly I haven't heard of this and it seems like a wide-open back door if AD allowed this.

Comment: If you have sufficient active directory rights, you can unlock your AD user accounts.

Comment: @RufusL: Never said it wasn't possible. Only stated that there may be some legal consequences/liability for not following best practices or for circumventing security features.